# Sending msg to iOS app from server manually

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, web-services, apple-push-notifications

I'm kind of starting programmer and on Objective-C. So I want to make an app for iOS that receives messages from a server. These messages are inputed manually, and send to all iOS connected to the server. People connected will receive a `Push Notification`, if they aren't connected to internet they will receive when they do and run the app.
So my question is: do I need to use a server to do this (sending messages for multiple iPhones)? In case of yes, with is the best server? TCP/socket?

Comment: In a small project we used a node.js backend. In the iOS app we used SocketRocket. It should all be pretty simple to setup, there are many examples and tutorials.

Comment: You may use Apple Push Notification. You may use python to setup server and can send notification to specific user using there device ID

Comment: I don't want to specify any user, I want to send to all the users at same time. The solution using python for server setup sounds great! Can it result any delay problems or maybe some user don't get the notification? thx

Comment: You'll always have this problem with APN. You can't have the guarantee  that the push notification will be received (neither can you be sure that it won't be delayed)

Answer (score 0):

If your only purpose behind using  is to send push notifictaion message, then you dont need to spend on that. There are some service providers available which allow you to send notification from there website. for ex: you can use urbanairship. You need to register device token from your Xcode project using their SDK, and then you can send notification from their website.

Thanks!